# MPI_COMM_RANK vs MPI_GROUP_RANK

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, fortran90

I tried to group 8 processors into two subgroups. One of the subgroup contains 2 processors, say, their ranks are 0 and 1. I don't need the other group for the current example. The code snippet in the context below is what I used to reach this goal. However, I kept obtaining error messages.

One of the error message I got is as the following:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
PMPI_Comm_rank(121): MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x7fff5a451e10) failed
PMPI_Comm_rank(73).: Null communicator.
```

If I change the statement in line 15 to `call MPI_GROUP_RANK(...)` then there is no error message shown. However, I don't know whether I can use group_rank as an input argument of the subroutines like `MPI_SEND` or `MPI_RECV`. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

Lee

```
01 program main
02   include 'mpif.h'
03   integer :: ierr, irank, num_procs, base_group
04   integer :: incl_list(2), new_group, new_comm, new_rank
05   call MPI_Init ( ierr )
06   call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_comm_world, irank, ierr )
07   call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_comm_world, num_procs, ierr)
08   call MPI_COMM_GROUP( MPI_comm_world, base_group, ierr)
09   
10   incl_list(1) = 0
11   incl_list(2) = 1
12   
13   call MPI_GROUP_INCL( base_group, 2, incl_list, new_group, ierr )
14   call MPI_COMM_CREATE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, new_comm, ierr ) 
15   call MPI_COMM_RANK( new_comm, new_rank, ierr ) 
16   call MPI_Finalize ( ierr ) 
17 end program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_COMM_CREATE` returns `MPI_COMM_NULL` in those ranks that are not included in `new_group`. Calling `MPI_COMM_RANK` with `MPI_COMM_NULL` results in the error you are getting. You should use an `IF` statement to prevent it:

```
call MPI_COMM_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, new_comm, ierr)
if (new_comm /= MPI_COMM_NULL) then
  !
  ! The process is part of new_group - do something useful
  !
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(new_comm, new_rank, ierr)
  ! ...
else
  !
  ! The process is not part of new_group - do nothing
  !
end if
```